# How can i generate and use unique deviceId for iOS devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, udid

In my previous app,I was using the below mentioned code to generate unique deviceId for iOS devices.But the problem is that it will generate a new code everytime when the app is reinstalled.How can i do this properly?

```
-(NSString*)uniqueIDForDevice //new..
{
    NSString* uniqueIdentifier = nil;
    if( [UIDevice instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(identifierForVendor)] ) { // >=iOS 7
        uniqueIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    }
    else
    { //<=iOS6, Use UDID of Device
        CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
        //uniqueIdentifier = ( NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);- for non- ARC
        uniqueIdentifier = ( NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid));// for ARC
        CFRelease(uuid);
    }

    return uniqueIdentifier;
}
```

Comment: Did you look at all the duplicate questions?

Comment: I tried may of them.But i did'nt find any code the save the udid and use it even if the app is uninstalled.

Comment: get one and store it in the keychain (if there isn't already one there)

Comment: did that solve your problem .. ok sounds great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [This](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore) link to UICKeyChainStore . I have added the following method call

`[self getDeviceIdFromKeychain];` in appDelegate application`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
-(void)getDeviceIdFromKeychain
{
    NSString *deviceID = [UICKeyChainStore stringForKey:DEVICE_ID_FROM_KEYCHAIN_REFERENCE_APP service:nil];
    NSLog(@"deviceID from Keychain = (%@)",deviceID);

    //if vandorid from keychain is not nil
    if (deviceID)
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:deviceID forKey:DEVICE_ID];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
//else it goes for new vendorid and then stored it to keychan
else if (deviceID == (id)[NSNull null] || deviceID.length == 0 )
{
    NSString *newDeviceId;
    newDeviceId=[[self class] deviceUUID];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:newDeviceId forKey:DEVICE_ID];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [UICKeyChainStore setString:newDeviceId forKey:DEVICE_ID_FROM_KEYCHAIN_REFERENCE_APP  service:nil];
    NSLog(@"new deviceID = (%@)",newDeviceId);
}

}
+ (NSString *)deviceUUID
{
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]])
        return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];

    @autoreleasepool {

        CFUUIDRef uuidReference = CFUUIDCreate(nil);
        CFStringRef stringReference = CFUUI

DCreateString(nil, uuidReference);
        NSString *uuidString = (__bridge NSString *)(stringReference);
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:uuidString forKey:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        CFRelease(uuidReference);
        CFRelease(stringReference);
        return uuidString;
    }
}
```

And i use them like this...(in my signinViewcontroller)

```
NSString *deviceIDfromNSUserDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:DEVICE_ID ];
    NSLog(@"deviceID from NSUserDefaults = (%@)",deviceIDfromNSUserDefaults);
```

Answer (score 2):

first of all get vendorId(uniqueID) than store it to keychain

```
// Fetch vendorID from keychain first, if it exists then use it or fetch vendorID 

//if user delete app and again install app than he get vendorID from keychain(if he hasn't cleared it)

NSString *vendorID = [UICKeyChainStore stringForKey:@"KEY TO SAVE TO Keychain" service:nil];
NSLog(@"VendorID from Keychain - %@",vendorID);

//if vandorid from keychain is not nil
if (vendorID)
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:vendorID forKey:@"vendorId"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

//else it goes for new vendorid and then stored it to keychan
else
{
    vendorID = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];

    [UICKeyChainStore setString:vendorID forKey:@"KEY TO SAVE TO Keychain"  service:nil];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:vendorID forKey:@"vendorId"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    NSLog(@"VendorID Local - %@",vendorID);
}
```

i use [this](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore) class to save and retrive vendorID from keyChain!

just take one look at this.hope it will help you

Comment: Are you sure this code works?I have limited time to spend.My issue  is that the app generates new deviceid each time when we install a new app on the same device.

Comment: YES i've tested it very well and by the way i use it in many of my apps

Comment: But can we use vendorID if we are not using iAds in the app?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below

```
+ (NSString *)deviceUUID
{
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]])
        return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];

    @autoreleasepool {

        CFUUIDRef uuidReference = CFUUIDCreate(nil);
        CFStringRef stringReference = CFUUIDCreateString(nil, uuidReference);
        NSString *uuidString = (__bridge NSString *)(stringReference);
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:uuidString forKey:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        CFRelease(uuidReference);
        CFRelease(stringReference);
        return uuidString;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not working..I have installed my app three times and the app had generated 3 different udid each time.

Comment: for that case you must go for keychain purpose to store it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using UUID to generate unique number. I doubt whether it is allowed to use vender ID if we are not using iAds in app.
I have achieved this by generating UUID and then storing into the keychain.
Keychain will store your UUID till user will not do Hard reset which is rare case.

As no API is provided by Apple to get unique device ID we have to find ways like this.

Comment: Why do you don't we aren't allowed to use vender ID? Using `identifierForVendor` is perfectly valid and is allowed when not using iAds. It has nothing to do with iAds. The reason that there is no API provided by Apple is because they deprecated it in iOS 6 and then removed it completely in iOS7 because for privacy reasons we aren't allowed to identify uniquely identify the user to a device. This has all been documented by Apple and can be found using google. @iosDeveloper_Junior this will probably apply to some of your other questions in comments to.